# MVC ASP.NET Writing to database is looping unintentionally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio

I'm very new to MVC and ASP.NET, but I've come across a weird issue.

I'm adding one entry to my database, then saving the changes, but that is not what happens.

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult EggRecieved()
    {
        //CHECK IF THEY HAVE RECIEVED EGG IN LAST DAY

        var user = db.PDCUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name);
        var userId = user.Id;

        var possibleEggs = db.PkmnDatas.Where(x => x.CanBeEgg == true);
        var rand = new Random();
        var no = rand.Next(0, possibleEggs.Count());
        var pokemonArray = possibleEggs.ToArray();
        var pokemon = pokemonArray[rand.Next(0, pokemonArray.Count())];
        Boolean? isMale = null;
        if (pokemon.GenderRatio != null)
        {
            isMale = rand.Next(0, 1000) < pokemon.GenderRatio1.ChanceMale * 1000;
        }
        var isShiny = 1 == rand.Next(1,Constants.SHINYCHANCE);
        //GET THE ABILITIES

        db.PlayerPkmns.Add(new PlayerPkmn
        {
            PkmnDataId = pokemon.Id,
            Nickname = pokemon.Name,
            IsMale = (bool)isMale,
            Nature = rand.Next(1, 25),
            Ability = 1,
            EggObtained = DateTime.Now,
            Shiny = isShiny,
            CurrentTrainerId = userId,
            OriginalTrainerId = userId,
            StepsToHatch = Constants.TOTALSTEPSFOREGGHATCH
        });

        db.SaveChanges();

        return EggRecieved();
    }
```

When I click a button I call this method, then the server takes half a minute and says it cannot access the view.

Then I check my database and I have 500+ new rows of data.

I'm not sure what's happening, but it looks like it is continuously calling this method and writing to the database.

Anyone know why, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are recursively calling the method in the end, with

```
return EggRecieved();
```

You should return an `ActionResult` there, like

```
return View("MyView");
```

Comment: I feel very stupid.
Late night coding is not the most effective

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because int the return statement, you wrote:

```
return EggRecieved();
```

It means you are calling the same method again and it stuck in endless loop throwing error. Remove that with your View or Json or etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrote at the end of code is return EggRecieved() that is worng,
you need return view() that you want. 
so replace EggRecieved to view(); because when you return EggRecieved() then it makes recursive loop and call each time
thank you